How to resolve module incompatibilities in NodeJS application
I am having this annoying issue when attempting to build my nestjs application.
> npm run build
src/shared/infrastructure/event-store/events-bridge.ts:31:5 - error TS2322: Type 'ChangeStream<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeStream<Document, ChangeStreamDocument<Document>>'.
  Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("C:/Users/***/repositories/nestjs-architecture/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").ChangeStreamOptions & { writeConcern?: never; }' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/***/repositories/nestjs-architecture/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").ChangeStreamOptions & { writeConcern?: never; }'.
      Type 'ChangeStreamOptions & { writeConcern?: never; }' is not assignable to type 'ChangeStreamOptions'.
        The types of 'session.clientOptions' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'MongoOptions' is missing the following properties from type 'MongoOptions': keepAlive, keepAliveInitialDelay

31     this.changeStream = this.eventStore
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error(s).

I seems typeorm uses major version 5.x.x of mongodb, while mongoose uses 6.x.x.
This results in differences in type declarations in the mongodb.d.ts files.
I can't seem to resolve this issue. I've attempted to roll back mongoose to a older version, that depends on mongodb 5.x.x, but then other TS compiler issues occur.
I am not super well-versed in resolving TS type incompatibilities, so was hoping for some guidelines.
Feel free to try it out yourselves:
Repo: https://github.com/EbolaNerd/nestjs-architecture

npm install
npm run build
TS error occurs

I tried to roll back the mongoose version to depend on mongodb major version 5.x.x. but then other incompatibilities occur.

for me, i resolve the problem by adding this line in package.json:
"overrides": {
"mongodb": "6.6.2"
},

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
